# MooTools get class that contains some text

Tags: mootools

Is it possible to get a class that contains some name? I have many classes with repeated part of the name, like: `first_class`, `second_class`, `third_class` etc.

I want to do something like:

```
$('selector').getChildren('.*_class')
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

MooTools uses the [CSS selectors in the W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors). So you could use `[class*="bar"]` like this: `$('myDiv').getElements('[class*="_class"]')`.

Just keep in mind if the search string is too generic you might also target other elements. Adding a common class could be a better idea, or even try to match some DOM pattern in the relations between elements.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h49s551s/

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to add a common class name to each item, i.e.

```
<div class = "first_class common_classname">foo</div>
```

then call your objects by using the common class name. Another solution is to call them all at once

```
$('selector').getChildren('first_class, second_class, thirdclass')
```